# Static IP for Wifi Centos 7

Tags: centos, ip

Can someone explain to me how to setup a static ip for wifi on CentOs 7?

This the configuration file I have for the network using DHCP:

```
ESSID="Network name"
MODE=Managed
KEY_MGMT="key type"
SECURITYMODE="leftout"
TYPE=Wireless
IEEE_8021X_EAP_METHODS=TTLS
IEEE_8021X_IDENTITY="username"
IEEE_8021X_PASSWORD_FLAGS=user
IEEE_8021X_INNER_AUTH_METHODS=PAP
IEEE_8021X_CA_CERT="leftout"
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME="Network name"
UUID="leftout"
ONBOOT=yes
```

I tried changing BOOTPROTO to static and adding my own IP. All I ended up getting was a second IP address along side my DHCP one that wasn't even used.

Thank you.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_Command_Line_Interface.html

Comment: @jordanm It doesn't say anything about a static ip on a wireless connection, just on a direct connection. Is it not possible to do it with a wireless connection? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @dylan7 sure it is, just take wlan0 instead of eth0. And make sure that your Router has DHCP off or at least define a IP range where it will accept self assigned IPs.

Comment: @derty How do you determine that IP range that a router with DHCP will accept? I do not have access to the router to turn DHCP off. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @dylan7 First things first, please edit your configuration file into your question. It is that file you (should have) created in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` it should be called something like `ifcfg-wlan0`.

Comment: @derty: I added the configuration file for the DHCP address. I also explained the edits I made and how they failed. However, I took the edits out, since they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is create a file called `ifcfg-wlan0` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` and fill it with this:
*adapt to however you need it*

```
DEVICE=wlan0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=192.168.1.110
```

After restarting the network interface or restarting the hole system, take a look at your interfaces with `ifconfig`.
You should be able to see your network with the corresponding IP address.